# Django Rest Framework: Handle Many-to-Many relationship

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework

The requirement is "I want to insert person with the person groups selection and also at the time of Creating person group I can choose persons for that particular group".

I've added two models in my **models.py** and manage many to many relationship between.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class PersonGroup(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    groupName = models.CharField(max_length=30)    
    detail = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Person(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    personId = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    personName = models.CharField(max_length=20)    
    state = models.IntegerField()
    personGroup = models.ManyToManyField(PersonGroup, related_name="person_list", blank=True)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    personGroup = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=PersonGroup.objects.all(), many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = '__all__'

class PersonGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    person_list = PersonSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = PersonGroup
        fields = '__all__'
```

The above code help me to create person with personGroup selection
[image]

But, I also want to add persons selection at the time of create personGroup. Currently at the time of creating personGroup I'm not allowed to enter persons.
[image]

Please let me know if there any solution by which I can also select available persons at the time of person group creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `person_list` field in the `PersonGroupSerializer` is on read only, so you can't modify it using the API.

`person_list = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Person.objects.all(), many=True)`

Try removing this arg.

You might also want to switch to a ForeignKey field instead of slugged.

Comment: remove read only argument works. also manage the relationship in the same field.
Thanks.